# maven pack too many jars to WEB-INF/lib, clear the local repository and re-execut mvn can make things right

Tags: maven

In our company, thousands projects are build on 3 servers, with mvn commands. 
A few projects occasionally pack too many jars to its WEB-INF/lib folder, the unwanted jars looks like another projects business code and its dependencies.

This is 
[the diff in WEB-INF/lib between right one(left) and too many jars one(right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LvBQ.png)

The jar in red frame looks like another project' jars, project name is "jd-common", and the other green jar on right is another project's dependencies.

This situation always reappeared until I clear local repository.

I guess the another project uses "mvn install" to install jars into local repository on build server, and our project is actually depend on jd-common-cached and jd-common-util only.

**How can I avoid this?! Thanks for help.**

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If a jar is included in WEB-INF/lib, it's because your project is depending on it...

Comment: @Tunaki yes, this is what we expected, but only a few project will pack some unexpected jars until we clear the local repo.

Comment: Could edit your question: list your pom.xml content and dependency:tree output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if the jars are there - you depend on them. You may depend on them implicitly (transitive dependencies). Run `mvn dependency:tree` to list all the dependencies (including transitive). You may find out that you depend on another project that in turn depends on those red/green jars.

Second, on the Build Server you don't want to share local repo with other projects. That's why, at least in Jenkins, there is an option Use Private Repository - this way all the project are going to be separated. This protects you from the situation when the artifact is not in remote repo anymore but the build is still green since that artifact is in local repo. But this has nothing to do with the problem you described.

Comment: thanks for answer.  Use separated local repo can help, but my boss and I want to know the root cause. mvn dependency:tree shows our project only depend on "jd-common-cached" and "jd-common-util". They are jars exported by project "jd-common". The jars in red frame are jd-common's sub-modules, but they are business module and not deployed in remote repository. I think it appears in our project because of  jd-common build with "mvn install" command on this server.   How can I share the jd-common's  pom.xml with you? it may help.

Comment: This is the files. http://pan.baidu.com/s/1nurrXyT . thanks.  "tree.txt" is the dependency:tree reuslt. The "too_many_jars.txt" list the WEB-INF/lib of wrong war, and the "right_jars.txt" list the packing reuslt after clear the local repository.

Comment: Thanks~ we finally found the reason~, and solved by using separate local repository for each project.

Answer (score 0):

It's finally be resolved!

The project A depend on a jar which deployed by another project B, the depend jar is a sub-module in B. (A->B)

Unfortunately：

```
 1. A and B are packaged on the same build server
 2. B's sub-module jar has the parent config in its pom.xml.
 3. B use "mvn clean install -DskipTests" as the build command, so all the B's modules are installed in local repository.
```

Maven always package the local installed jar, and use the installed jar's pom file to find the sub dependencies, so when maven is executed, project A found that:"one of my depended jar has a parent, it's B, and all the B's sub-modules are found in local repository because of B installed all of them, I should package them all!".